# How to make myself administrator with no perms on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I would like to make myself administrator on my windows 10 machine but have no perms (My dad has the only admin account) How could I make myself administrator?

Comment: “How could I make myself administrator?” - You don’t

Comment: This question doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Ask your dad. Only an admin can change your account to administrator.

Comment: I feel bad potentially misleading the young. there is likely a way to make yourself admin provided you have physical access to the computer and can turn it on and boot it. That said, we can't help people bypass the will of the system owner, so you'll have to do your own detective work. The only hint I'll give is that the ability to affect the boot is key. Its also easy to get caught, so beware.